# Use part of first row and part of second row as column headers in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have  a smiliar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719952/delete-part-of-a-row-in-pandas-shift-up-part-of-a-row-align-column-headings).

But somehow the solotion is not working, my dataframe looks like:

```
    Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3      Ist 1-4     Plan 1-4    HoRe 04     Plan
0   D           B           Hil           V Gesamt:     -83053      -83628    -262596     -257276
1   V           V           Vor            Perso        -896        -833    -2720         -2504
```

So basically I need to have for the first four columns the row number 0 as headers (D           B           Hil                 V Gesamt:) and then the last 4 columns (Ist 1-4     Plan 1-4    HoRe 04     Plan), when I run the script:

```
#set first row by columns names
df.iloc[0,:] = df.columns

#reset_index
df = df.reset_index()
#set columns from first row
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:]
df.columns.name= None
#remove first row
df.iloc[1:,:]
```

its still wrong, the outcome does not change.

My output should be:

```
    D   B   Hil     V Gesamt        Ist 1-4     Plan 1-4    HoRe 04     Plan
0   V    V  Vor     Perso           -896        -833       -2720         -2504
```

Comment: could u post an example of ur expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can convert first 4 values of first row to list and add to all columns names:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:4].tolist() + df.columns[4:].tolist()
#alternative
#df.columns = np.concatenate([df.iloc[0,:4], df.columns[4:]])
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   D  B  Hil V Gesamt:  Ist 1-4  Plan 1-4  HoRe 04  Plan
0  V  V  Vor     Perso     -896      -833    -2720 -2504
```